# widget logic on custom product type taxonomy

Tags: wordpress, widget, logic

I created a custom post type by the custom post plugin and now i created new post-type by taxonomy. My requirement is that how can i use the widget logic in that taxonomy page.

i used the following code in the widget for widget logic and i cant get any result for that.

```
is_tax('branes-range')||is_single()&&(get_post_type()=='products');
```

this is taxonomy 'product-types' page and i have created is under products custom post and 'branes-range' is taxonomy type. Now i want to get the widget logic in 'branes-range' page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use this widget Logic:**

```
is_tax('your_taxonomy_name', 'your_taxonomy')
```

Here no need to use the Post type name.